# Anyone using TortoiseSVN with SSL and a relative path for the bugtraq:url?

Tags: https, tortoisesvn, artifact

(**NOTE:** All fake URL's below are shown as https:/ or http:/, with just a single slash.)

I've spent most of the day trying to get TortoiseSVN to work with my bug tracking system using a relative URL for the **bugtraq:url** parameter.  I'm using SSL on the repository with a self-issued certificate.  I'm using VisualSVN for the server and client pieces and Versioned.com's "Artifacts" for the bug tracking piece.

Seems like the only way I can make the embedded hyperlink (e.e. %BUGID%) work to fire up the browser is to use an absolute path for **bugtraq:url**, like this:

https:/my-server/svn/ProjectName/trunk/Bugs/artifacts.html#%BUGID%

I've tried every variation I can think of for relative paths (using "^/bla") without any luck.  I'm getting a link showing up in the commit and log dialogs, but when I click on it it's a NOP.  Here's what the TortoiseSVN docs say:

==

> You can also use relative URLs instead of absolute ones. This is useful when your issue tracker is on the same domain/server as your source repository. In case the domain name ever changes, you don't have to adjust the bugtraq:url property. There are two ways to specify a relative URL:
>
> If it begins with the string ^/ it is assumed to be relative to the repository root. For example, ^/../?do=details&id=%BUGID% will resolve to http:/tortoisesvn.net/?do=details&id=%BUGID% if your repository is located on http:/tortoisesvn.net/svn/trunk/.
>
> A URL beginning with the string / is assumed to be relative to the server's hostname. For example /?do=details&id=%BUGID% will resolve to http:/tortoisesvn.net/?do=details&id=%BUGID% if your repository is located anywhere on http:/tortoisesvn.net.

==

I'm beginning to think that this is a limitation of either: A) using HTTPS on my VisualSVN Server; or B) trying to access a project on the same box as the repository but that's stored separate from the repository.

Comment: What happens when you try? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Actually, nothing happens.  That's the problem.  If I use a string like "https://my-server" for the bugtraq:url, then when I click on a linked BUGID in the TortoiseSVN dialogs, my IE browswer fires up.  If I have anything else in there (like "^" or "/" which are used for relative paths), then it's a NO-OP.  Nuttin' happens.

Comment: The thing is: I'm seeing LOTS and LOTS of bugtraq:url examples on the web for a scenario like this, but **all** of them are using the HTTP prototcol, not SSL.  So I'm beginning to wonder whether SSL works at all with relative **bugtraq:url** parameters.

Comment: I ended up "fixing" this buy using an absolute path for the **bugtraq:url** parameter and then I had my business partner modify *his* HOSTS file to remap my server name to an IP address like this: 99.888.77.66 my-server